# How to connect to L2TP/IPSec VPN server?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, vpn

I am trying to connect my Raspberry Pi (Raspbian) to my L2TP/IPSec VPN Server (a Synology NAS) but I'm having a hard time doing so.
I've read some tutorials but it all seams so complicated, I'm a bit surprised it's not more simple than what I tried.

I am not trying to set a VPN server running on my RPi, just trying to connect it as a client to an already set server.

Any idea on how to do so?
Thanks :-)

Comment: Have you found a solution? Because I'm trying to do the same thing. Thank you

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not :-/